# why does Terraform Refresh make changes to my tfstate file outputs?

Tags: refresh, terraform

We maybe using our state file incorrectly or we maybe using `terraform refresh` incorrectly.

Anyway I want to keep track of which key (primary or secondary) is being used for a particular resource. After `terraform apply` we get an output like this

```
Outputs:

is_storage_account_primary_key_active = true
```

When you run `terrraform refresh` at any point it updates the output to

```
is_storage_account_primary_key_active = false
```

I would rather not let that happen and that the `refresh` command not update my outputs as we are using that value to determine which key to use the next time we run `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`

Any ideas / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of an output, that sounds like something that should be a `data` or something else able to be stored in the state.

Comment: hi @MattSchuchard so we are using `data "terraform_remote_state" ...` that points to this state file to determine what the last key was used. This allows us to switch between keys. So when terraform refresh changes the outputs that's the problem... I am wondering maybe using `-target` option?